# Adding logo in visual force email template

Tags: visualforce, email

I am using a vf email template. I understand to use logo in a vf template i cannot leverage static resources, rather have to keep the logo in documents folder.
But how can i dynamically access the url of the image from the document folder in the template so that the template can be deployed to higher orgs

Answer (score 5):

**Refer to:**
https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?urlname=Why-images-stored-as-static-resources-cannot-be-seen-in-emails-sent-using-VF-email-templates-1327108316482&language=en_US

**It states:**

To solve this problem, images should be stored in documents and with "Externally Available Image" checked. The image will be available by using the following markup:

```
<apex:image id="theImage" 
value="https://c.<instance>.content.force.com/servlet/servlet.ImageServer?id=<document_id>&oid=<organization_id>" 
width="200" height="200"/>
```

Save the  instance value in a custom setting and refer the value dynamically inside url..

Comment: But how does that help in migration. When the org changes the document id and ordId will also change.  Could there be a way where the document id and oid be dynamically accessed so that one does not need to manually keep changing the id values as the template moves up.

Comment: @starhunter - I guess you can use a custom component with controller and query the orgId and documentId dynamically based on certain conditions and use that component in your template.

Answer (score -1):

You can create force.com site and use the force.com site url+document Id in email template.

Thanks,

Comment: I believe in that scenario too, I would be hard coding the document id. I was looking for a way by which the document id be dynamically accessed as the template moves from lower environment to higher environments.